# pdftools: Embeded NUL in string

Tags: r, poppler

I'm trying to download a file and read it's info automatically, from the following link:

http://www.leyes.congreso.gob.pe/Documentos/2016_2021/Proyectos_de_Ley_y_de_Resoluciones_Legislativas/PL0361420181108.pdf

The problem is that when I try to read the information on the pdf, I get an error. It seems to happen on and off, I can't see a good reason why. The error appears to be Linux only.

```
library(pdftools)
link = "http://www.leyes.congreso.gob.pe/Documentos/2016_2021/Proyectos_de_Ley_y_de_Resoluciones_Legislativas/PL0361420181108.pdf"
download.file(link, "somefile.pdf")
pdf_info("somefile.pdf")
Error in poppler_pdf_info(loadfile(pdf), opw, upw) : 
  Embedded NUL in string.
```

What else I've tried:

- Tried downloading using mode = "wb"
- Tried downloading with httr using the write_disk method
- Tried downloading manually on windows and it works! :(

My suspicion is that it has to do with the way I'm downloading the file. But, I don't know what alternatives I should be trying.

Answer (score 2):

So, this isn't going to work at all. There is no text in that document except for page break characters. It's all images.

If `rJava` works on your system and you can and are comfortable installing packages from untrusted sources such as GitHub them you can install [`pdfbox`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/pdfbox/) <sub>(note the security warning there as I haven't updated the `pdfbox` JARs but the only vuln is a potential process denial of service)</sub> to validate this since it's less fragile than `pdftools`.

When I use the `httr::write_disk()` or `curl::curl_download()` methods to get the PDF (boy that takes a while in the U.S., too) I then did:

```
pdfbox::extract_text("~/Downloads/ill-bet-this-is-all-images.pdf")
## # A tibble: 14 x 2
##     page text 
##    <int> <chr>
##  1     1 "\n" 
##  2     2 "\n" 
##  3     3 "\n" 
##  4     4 "\n" 
##  5     5 "\n" 
##  6     6 "\n" 
##  7     7 "\n" 
##  8     8 "\n" 
##  9     9 "\n" 
## 10    10 "\n" 
## 11    11 "\n" 
## 12    12 "\n" 
## 13    13 "\n" 
## 14    14 "\n"
```

Boom: no text.

You'll need to use some of the rOpenSci image-to-text OCR tools to get anything meaningful out of that document.

Comment: I am indeed using OCR. However, `tesseract` calls `pdf_info()` on the document before going through the ocr routine, probably because it needs to know how many pages are in the document.  I simplified the problem to this particular error as I thought it was related to how I was downloading (given it's intermittent nature)

Comment: No, I'm 99% sure it's `pdftools`. If you can get `rJava` working `pdfbox` is def an alternative.

Comment: The `Embedded NUL in string` bug has been fixed in pdftools 2.0.